# Fragment mysql database connection

Tags: android, mysql

This is my fragment and i have database adapter,but the listview doesnt get populated.

Here is my Code :

public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

```
public HomeFragment(){}

private TextView txt;
private String n = "";
public String s="";
public ListView lst;
public Button btn;
private HomeAdapter adapter;
private List<homeinfo> items;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState)
{

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);


   lst=(ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView);
   btn=(Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button1);

   btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
   {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent intentDemo=new Intent(getActivity(),Testing.class);
        startActivity(intentDemo);
    }
});


   items=new ArrayList<homeinfo>();
   adapter=new HomeAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),items);
   lst.setAdapter(adapter);




   Thread thread=new Thread(doInBackground);
    thread.start();


    return rootView;
}
```

Runnable doInBackground=new Runnable()
     {

```
    @Override
    public void run() 
    {
        items = homeservice.getAllRadio("http://********.com/");
        runOnUiThread(runOnUi);
    }

 };

 Runnable runOnUi=new Runnable()
 {

    @Override
    public void run() 
    {
        for(homeinfo radioitems:items)
        {
            adapter.add(radioitems);
        }

        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

 };
```

protected void runOnUiThread(Runnable runOnUi2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

```
}
```

}

Comment: You create Adapter with empty list, so you got empty ListView. Show us the code of doInBackground RUnnable and this adapter

Comment: It appears your IDE has generated an empty method stub for `runOnUiThread()`, so the call to it is doing nothing.

Comment: doInBackground RUnnable and adapter upadated bro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `runOnUiThread()` is an element of the Activity class. To access it from a Fragment try the following:

```
getActivity().runOnUiThread(runOnUi);
```